# Use updated let value from different file in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to import string value from second.tsx to first.tsx and than display it, but it imports only default value of that message variable, so it shows "My message".

But I need to import updated value based on setMessage() function.

How can I do it?

first.tsx

```
import { newMessage } from "second.tsx";

export const First = ({}: props): JSX.Element => {    
    return (
      <>
        <p>{newMessage}</p>
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

second.tsx

```
let message = "My message";
const someArray = [];


export const Second = ({}: props): JSX.Element => {    

  const setMessage = () => {
    switch (someArray.length) {
      case 1:
        message = "Size is 1";
        break;
      case 2:
        message = "Size is 2";
        break;

    }
  };

  return (
    <li>
      <p>{message}</p>
     </li>
  );
};

export const newMessage = message;
```

Comment: The message is `My message` because you don't change it. You aren't changing it because you don't call the `setMessage` function.

Comment: Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html to handle state in react functional components

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Declaring message as a module variable means that it will be shared by all that will import that module. You most likely need to useState and also use it as a component and not use that variable.

Comment: Primitive types such as string do not hold reference when assigned to another variable. `newMessage` will always be what it is initially assigned to - `"My message"`. But then again even if it would hold a reference you have render problem. You can solve this by lifting up the state with useState declaration, using react context or state management library.